# How does the EC Regulation on Insolvency Proceedings address cooperation between between EU and non-EU insolvency courts?

Tags: european-union, international, bankruptcy

In particular, I am curious how the EC Regulation on Insolvency Proceedings addresses issues with cross-border corporate groups. The UNCITRAL Model Law contains provisions on the cooperation of insolvency courts in international proceedings. Have similar provisions been translated into the EC Regulation? And if not, has the European Union entered into any cross-border protocols or other arrangements to coordinate proceedings with courts in other countries?